# How to get page wise email FLAG changes since last sync

Tags: imap

Gmail recently supported CONDSTORE CAPABILITY and which gives the feasibility of getting the flag changes since last sync.

Command for fetching changes:
. FETCH 1:* FLAGS (CHANGEDSINCE modseq)

Above command works nice if there are only few changes since last sync but it is not going to work in case of more number of changes since last sync. suppose client is not synced to Gmail server for long time. Here when I request for the changes since last sync then Gmail throws the huge response which my IMAP c-client is unable to process it.

Is there any page wise request for changes with CHANGEDSINCE. I know that there is one solution to fetch chunk wise like below, but it introduces lot of other manipulations which I don't want to do.

. FETCH 1:1000 FLAGS (CHANGEDSINCE modseq)

Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I think fetching per groups of messages is probably your best bet.  Unfortunately, there's no protocol method to limit the length of a response.

Comment: As you suggested if I use "fetching group of messages" technique  then I should do lot of requests to sync with huge mailboxes (consists of 10 lakhs emails). Our app deals with huge mailboxes, I think this logic is going to be expensive.